# Why can't I reshape to any dimensions?

Tags: matrix, bugs, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.3.0**

---

I am trying to reshape a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ array into a $n \times m$ array. It seems that if the matrix is defined via `SparseArray`, the `ArrayReshape` command doesn't care what $n$ and $m$ I choose, it always reshapes it to a $4 \times 2$ array.

In this code I try to reshape to $1 \times 8$:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
m = SparseArray[{i_, i_, i_} -> 1., {2, 2, 2}];
mt = ArrayReshape[m, {1, 8}];
MatrixForm[mt]
```

> $\begin{pmatrix}1.&0.\\ 0.&0.\\0.&0.\\0.&1.\end{pmatrix}$

Why does it work like that? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems to have something to do with `SparseArray`, despite what the docs say. `Dimensions@ArrayReshape[m, {1, 8}]` gives `{4, 2}`, but `Dimensions@ArrayReshape[Normal@m, {1, 8}]` gives `{1, 8}`.

Comment: In Mathematica 11 Miguels code produces a list with 8 entries (`{1,8}` dimensional)

Comment: Mi edition is 11.2  ...

Comment: bug introduced in 11.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ArrayReshape[SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten[m], {1, 8}]
(* or ArrayReshape[Flatten[m], {1, 8}] *)
```

> SparseArray[<2>,{1,8}]

```
Normal @ %
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

For the special case where the desired shape is a list with `Length` equal to `Times@@Dimensions[m]`, you can also use `` SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten ``:

```
SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten[m]
```

> SparseArray[<2>,{8}]

```
Normal @ %
```

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}

Comment: That's right @kglr but my aim is not a $1 \times 8$ array, but any $n \times m$ array. The $1 \times 8$ in the code was just an example.

Comment: @Miguel, this approach works for any `n` and `m`. For example, ``ArrayReshape[SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten[m], {5, 3}, x]`` gives `SparseArray[<9>,{5,3}] ` as it should

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Thank you @kglr

Comment: @MiguelBolín, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 5):

It seems one have to make `SparseArray` to `Normal` first to reshape it.

```
m=SparseArray[{i_,i_,i_}->1,{2,2,2}];
ArrayReshape[m,{1,8}]//Normal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But now

```
ArrayReshape[Normal@m,{1,8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not sure if this is by design or not.

Comment: Okay but then I loose the computation saving of SparseArray, right? When you make it Normal it adds all the zeros and you carry them along

Comment: @MiguelBolín that is right. THat was the only way I could find to get it to work.  I suggest you use Kglr solution using SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten which I did not know about.

Comment: `mt = SparseArray@ArrayReshape[Normal@m, {1, 8}][[1]]`

Comment: Or just `mt = SparseArray@ArrayReshape[Normal@m, {1, 8}]` for the `1 x 8`

Comment: I guess that has the same problem as Nasser's, right @BobHanlon ? You are adding the zeros and carrying them along.

Comment: @MiguelBolín No. What Bob is saying, is if you wan to use Normal as I did, then you need to apply `SparseArray` again to the result.  So this method requires calling `SparseArray` one more time. I assume then that "ArrayReshape[SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten[m], {1, 8}]" will be somewhat more efficient? may be some testings is needed on large array.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the timings for the approaches proposed by `kglr` and `Nasser` (modified):

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

m = SparseArray[{i_, i_, i_} -> 1., {16, 16, 16}];

(kglr = ArrayReshape[SparseArray`SparseArrayFlatten[m], #] & /@ {{1, 
      16^3}, {16^3, 1}, {128, 32}, {32, 128}}) // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

```
(nasser = SparseArray@ArrayReshape[Normal@m, #] & /@ {{1, 16^3}, {16^3, 
      1}, {128, 32}, {32, 128}}) // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

Verifying their equivalence

```
kglr === nasser

True
```